# Scala regex : capture between group

Tags: regex, scala

In below regex I need "test" as output but it gives complete string which matches the regex. How can I capture string between two groups?

```
val pattern = """\{outer.*\}""".r

 println(pattern.findAllIn(s"try {outer.test}").matchData.map(step => step.group(0)).toList.mkString)



Input : "try {outer.test}" 
expected Output : test 
current output : {outer.test}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may *capture* that part using:

```
val pattern = """\{outer\.([^{}]*)\}""".r.unanchored
val s = "try {outer.test}"

val result = s match {
  case pattern(i) => i
  case _ => ""
}
println(result)
```

The pattern matches

- `\{outer\.` - a literal `{outer.` substring
- `([^{}]*)`  - Capturing group 1: zero or more (`*`) chars other than `{` and `}` (see `[^{}]` negated character class)
- `\}`  - a `}` char.

NOTE: if your regex must match the whole string, remove the `.unanchored` I added to also allow partial matches inside a string.

See the [Scala demo online](https://rextester.com/AJSK34601).

Or, you may change the pattern so that the first part is no longer as consuming pattern (it matches a string of fixed length, so it is possible):

```
val pattern = """(?<=\{outer\.)[^{}]*""".r
val s = "try {outer.test}"
println(pattern.findFirstIn(s).getOrElse(""))
// => test
```

See [this Scala demo](https://rextester.com/WFWY19565).

Here, `(?<=\{outer\.)`, a positive lookbehind, matches `{outer.` but does not put it into the match value.